# Calculating HP for UA beast master animal companion

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana, animal-companions

I am a very new DM in DnD 5e, and one of my players is a ranger. As I was browsing through posts here and there we decided to use the UA, as everyone is saying the RAW ranger is lackluster. She obtained her wolf in a little side story, and I would like to set up the stats for her companion. I read through the UA, and it states:

> For   each    level   you gain    after   3rd,    your    animal
>   companion gains   an  additional  hit die and  increases  its hit points
>   accordingly.

Now this confuses me a lot, and upon further looking into how HP is calculated, I don't even understand the stats of the simple Wolf enemy.

So in the Monster Manual the HP of the wolf is 11 (2d8+2).

First question: How is this calculated? The average of 2d8 should be 10. 10+2 is 12.

Second question: What is the hit die of a wolf? If its 1d8, than in case the wolf is "level 1", its HP should be 10 (max hit die + con modifier). If it is considered to be level 2, its HP should be 17 (Max hit die + avg hit die + con modifier). What am I missing?

Third question: I found a post on a DnD reddit site where someone calculates the stats of a wolf in case the ranger is level 7. It goes like this:

> Wolf
>
> Medium beast, your alignment
>
> Armor Class 17
>
> Hit Points 35 (6d8+6)
>
> Speed 40 ft.
>
> STR 12 (+1)
>
> DEX 17 (+3)
>
> CON 12 (+1)
>
> INT 3 (-4)
>
> WIS 12 (+1)
>
> CHA 6 (-2)
>
> Proficiency Bonus +3
>
> Skills: Perception +4, Stealth +6, Skill of Choice, Skill of Choice
>
> Saving Throws: Str +4, Dex +6, Con +4, Int -1, Wis +4, Cha +1
>
> Senses: passive Perception 14
>
> Actions Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: +6 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 11 (2d4 + 6) piercing damage. If the target is a creature, it must succeed on a DC 12 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone.

I think I was able to figure out everything, except the HP.

My first assumption was to start with the given base 11 HP as a level 3 companion. Than at level 4, it gains an additional 7 (5 hit die +con modifier). And the same thing goes on for level 5, 6 and 7, to a total of 11+4*7 totaling 39.

If I start from the 2d8+2, and just add a hit die each time the ranger levels up, I can understand the 6d8 mentioned in the post, but I don't get the +6 modifier. Shouldn't it be +10? +2 base modifier at level 3, and +2 for each 4 levels totaling at +10. And now the problem is that averaging this value leads to 40, not 39, this problem is coming from my first question.

I am completely lost here.

One last question. The `Bite` attack says +6 to hit. I can explain this as the DEX modifier became +3, and the proficiency bonus also became +3, however I dont understand the reason why DEX modifier is used for the `Bite` attack instead of STR.

Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Hi Gábor Erdős, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Also, we usually ask that you post only one question per post. However, I believe your ones are sufficiently related for it not to be an issue, save for the last one, maybe. I recommend you split that off. It is also likely to have an answer on this site already.

Comment: @Szega Oh, I see; the question title is asking about HP, and the bite attack isn't about HP. I think it's probably not a biggie _this_ time, but I agree that it is technically beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Related Question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/how-many-hit-points-does-the-beast-conclave-rangers-animal-companion-have (not quite a dupe given the specific questions about the Reddit calculation in this one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The UA Ranger's wolf companion

To answer your questions:

1. "The average of 2d8 should be 10. 10+2 is 12." This explanation by [kriivi](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/11660/kviiri) via a comment is better than my original attempt, so I'm going to quote it here:

   > Expected value is linear, which means that the sum of individual die values will do. In the case of d8, the expected value (or more intuitively, average of possible outcomes) is 4.5, which means the expected value of 2d8 is simply 2*4.5 = 9.
2. Monsters and PCs use different rules, and as such, the number of hit die a monster has does not reflect its level in the same way that a PC would.

   For a better relationship between the "level" of a monster (CR) and its HP, there are rules in the DMG for creating and balancing monsters, in particular a table showing how HP, AC, damage output, etc, related to a creature's CR.
3. The +6 that they are adding to the monster's HP comes from the fact that it should add +1 per hit die, in the same way that PCs do (I know I just said that monsters and PCs don't use the same rules, but this is one of the cases where they do). Since a PC's HP (past first level) is hit die + CON modifier, that's what's happening here. It's plus 6 because the monster has 6 hit die, and a CON modifier of 1.

   As for the total value of 35, I've noticed with monsters, they tend to take the "overall" average hit die values (as per kriivi's quote above), rather than average 1 by 1 (like PCs do). So the average for 2d8 for a PC would be 10, but the average for a monster would be 9; hence the default wolf's total of 11 HP (9 plus the +2 from their CON modifier). For a Beast Master wolf, the first 2d8 were using "monster averages", hence total 11. From then on, the next 4d8 were done using "player averages", meaning +5 per hit die (so actually +6 because of the +1 from CON modifier). Hence the total HP is 11 + (6 × 4) = 35.

Lastly: Some monsters use DEX instead of STR for their attacks, particularly if it's a "natural weapon" (like a wolf's bite). This appears to be the case here.

### Using the RAW Beast Master

If the UA seems a bit complicated (given that you're a first time DM), I'd recommend using the RAW Beast Master in the PHB (the HP calculation is a lot simpler, since it's just 4 × ranger level), but with the following houserule:

> Use a bonus action, instead of an action, to command the beast to attack.

This houserule has been suggested in [an article on D&DBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/669-ranger-101-beast-master).

This houserule has been also discussed on RPG.SE before, see: [If Beast Master Rangers could use bonus actions to attack with their companion, what problems would occur?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128701/35259)

I answered that question too, since my first time DMing was also for a player who made a Beast Master ranger, and it worked well for us without making the character overpowered, but without feeling as underpowered as the RAW Beast Master without this houserule.

Comment: Thanks a lot, The other answer confused me a little again, but I think I will go with yours, as it is clear as day!

Comment: Just one more question about the expected values. If the one you said is correct, the expected value of 6d8 is 27. Adding the +6 con modifier it is 33, not 39 as I calculated, cause there is used independent expected values rounded up to 5. Which is the correct expected value than?

Comment: @GáborErdős Yeah, I came to 33 as well. I've been trying different calculations (assuming max value from the d8 at level 1, using average of d8 to be 4, 4.5, etc) and none of them come to 35. I've come to 33, 34, 36, 36.5 (which isn't a valid HP, but this is just me with a calculator), but nothing comes to 35.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is clearer now. My only problem is that I find this calculation inconsistent. If i just jump to level 7 out of nowhere, the expected value of the hit die will be 27 (6d8). But if I do it one by one, the expected values will be 5s right (4.5 rounded up)? So for example at level 4, the HP is going to be 17, and not 16.5. On level 5 it can be 23, if we round up twice, 22.5 if we round up once, or 22 if we dont round anything.

Comment: @GáborErdős I've noticed with monsters, they tend to take the "overall" average, rather than average 1 by 1 (like PCs do). So the average for 2d8 _for a PC_ would be 10, but the average _for a monster_ would be 9 (hence the 27). Oh... maybe that's how they got to 35. **EDIT:** Yep, that's why. The first 2d8 were using "monster averages", hence total 11. From then on, the next 4d8 were done using "player averages", meaning +5 per hit die (so actually +6 because of the +1 from CON modifier). 11 + (6 * 4) = 35

Comment: @GáborErdős Monsters gaining more HD usually doesn't happen, which might explain a part of this weirdness. It seems likely that it simply wasn't planned ahead, but you're correct in that for player HD you should use the expected value rounded up instead of the raw expected value (but only when "taking the average" instead of actually rolling)

Comment: Quick note to add - "Use a bonus action to command the beast to attack" has also now been considered by WotC. The recent [Class Features UA](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf) has two Beast Companion options with that ability. They also have better-scaling HP (CON mod + Ranger WIS mod + 5x Ranger level).

Comment: Hey NathanS, this answer is really helping me make sense of the stats for different companions. Any chance you know why the Panther's base HP is 13 with (3d8) though? Surely it should be 14 by monster rules ((4.5 * 3) rounded up) or 15 by player rules ((4.5 rounded up) * 3). 13 suggests it was monster rules rounded down?

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland If there's an odd number of hit die, it rounds down the last one, so 3d8 = 4.5 + 4.5 + 4 = 13 (I don't have the stats in front of me so I'm assuming there's no CON modifier?)

Comment: Ha, that's so bizarre, is doing that defined anywhere (I haven't read the DM, working purely from PHB) or is it just something you worked out? Your assumption is correct, no CON mod for the Panther as standard.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I don't think that's explained anywhere in the books, or at least, I don't recall an explanation; I think it's just something I either figured out or read someone else having figured it out. In fact, it might have been kriivi (there were more comments before) or possibly another commenter of a now-deleted comment... this was only a couple of months ago an yet it feels like many more months than that!

Answer (score 3):

## First

The average (expected value) of 2d8 is 9, not 10.

## Second

The rules for monsters and PC-s are separate. There is no such thing as a level 1 wolf (unless you awaken it to sentience and it gains a PC level). You are correct that its hit die is a d8.

## Third

To me it seems that either they miscalculated or are using different rules than you are (homebrew, table rules...). I believe your HP calculations are correct.

## Last

See monsters just being monsters, as above. The creators considered the wolf's jaws a finesse weapon.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So expected values are calculated as the whole average + 1, not as the expected values of separate die values?

Comment: @GáborErdős Expected value is linear, which means that the sum of individual die values will do. In the case of d8, the expected value (or more intuitively, average of possible outcomes) is 4.5, which means the expected value of 2d8 is simply 2*4.5 = 9.

Comment: @kviiri Ahh thanks! I think this caused my confusion. So they take the real expected value, just round it up right (thus the expected of d8 is 5)?

Comment: @GáborErdős Huh, I'm actually not sure what's the Monster Manual etc convention. I'll let Szega explain as they probably know better than I do :)

Comment: @kviiri Just to let you know, I've borrowed your comment for my answer, since you just did a way better job of explaining that than I did!

Comment: This is still unclear if i think about it. You said my calculation in my third question is correct meaning the HP should be 39. You also said the expected value of 2d8 is 9, thus the expected value of 6d8 is is 27, and adding the modifiers it comes out to 33. Which one is it? :D

Comment: @GáborErdős The companion is a mixture of two worlds in this regard. The base HP is from a monster, and for those HP is calculated with the expected value of the HD. But it progresses through (your) levels and I would assume hat it will gain HP as a PC would (rounding the HP gain, not the sum total). Bear in mind that this is UA (ie. unfinished).